# Why don't children find Mike scary?

Tags: pixar, monsters-inc, monsters-university

A major theme of *Monsters University* is that Mike just isn't scary. His teachers tell him this. Other students tell him this.

> Even the children at the end of *M.U.* aren't scared by his direct appearance. The kid at the end of *Monsters Inc.* is also more bemused than frightened when he sees Mike.

What I don't understand is, **why isn't Mike considered scary?**

[image: Scary Mike]

Granted, he isn't the most frightening monster around, but I still think children would be afraid of him. He's a green, scaly one-eyed creature with fangs and claws. While audiences might find him "cute", to the humans in the movies, he's a strange entity who sneaks into childrens' rooms at night.

It's especially egregious, given that all the other Oozma Kappa members evidently *are* scary, including this bozo:

[image]

What makes Mike so unscary in this world?

Comment: Are you looking for an in-universe explanation or an out-of-universe one. The latter is easier; he's fundamentally non-threatening, short and cute-looking with rounded teeth and small, nail-like claws. It would be possible to turn him into something unpalatable if they dramatically altered his character (if he was, for example seen to commit murder without remorse), but that ain't gonna happen.

Comment: @Richard He may be "cute" from our point of view, but I don't see how in-universe children wouldn't be afraid of a strange creature coming out of their closet in the middle of the night.

Comment: Blame it on Billy Crystal. Now if Jack Palance was behind Mike, now that would be scary.

Comment: @RogueJedi "I don't see how in-universe children wouldn't be afraid of a strange creature..." - you said it yourself. *In-universe* would be the operative term here.

Comment: @misha ...Yes? I'm asking why the children in the movie aren't afraid of him.

Comment: @RogueJedi Because they are in-universe children.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Unless children in this universe are fundamentally different than children in our own, they should still be afraid.

Comment: @RogueJedi They are part of the basic premise. There are two main premises here. One premise is that there are monsters - and that's why we don't ask how Wazowski can possibly be so smart when there is probably not enough space in him to house a developed brain. The other premise is that some of them - like Mike Wazowski - aren't scary. That's why we accept that children aren't scared of him. Those two are at the core of the story, kind of like Harry Potter having magic. I would imagine, however, that in other respects those children are supposedly similar to ones in our universe.

Comment: I don't think the pic spoils anything in the movie. Plus it's in the trailer..

Comment: Can anyone find a clip showing Mike trying to be scary? I'm wondering if he's able to do a good scary voice or if his voice is nonthreatening as usual, which would undermine whatever scariness he could achieve from his looks alone.

Comment: I can't help but wonder what makes him so different from Final Fantasy Ahriman, which have a lot of similarities with him, and which I find creepier.

Comment: In my opinion, Mike *is* scary. I would definitely be scared of him in my room in the darkness. But they needed a comic character, and Mike was the chosen one, so they made him "not scary"

Comment: He's an eyeball and a mouth, with arms and legs. Kids have eyeballs and mouths, and arms and legs. What's to be scared of?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hmm... Giant eyeball could creep out some people who had past trauma about being the "center of attention" (from being "different"; I know someone who had nightmares of walls of eyes), and that big mouth of his could be used so eat off someone's head, Venom style. But the way he was pictured, makes him look inoffensive.

Comment: @Clockwork: I mean, if the kid's scared of eyes, you probably want a monster with more eyes, not the smallest number of eyes it's possible to have.

Answer (score 16):

Ignoring the fact that Mike [palpably isn't scary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAQIW.png) (he's short and goofy looking, his teeth aren't especially sharp, his "claws" are kinda short, his giant eyeball makes him look vulnerable, his arms and legs seem puny and bandy) the reality is that in a world of scary monsters he's definitely the least scary.

> Alarms went off all over campus, sending Hardscrabble and her security guards racing to the lab.
> In the cabin, Mike tried to scare the children, But **they didn't find him scary. They thought he was cute!**
>
> <sub><sup>[Monsters University - Disney Press](https://archive.org/details/monstersuniversi0000unse_m6e3)</sup></sub>

Added to that, the children that Mike tries to scare at the end of MU are likely to be those who've **already been scared half to death on a regular basis by the most scary monsters in the Monster world**. By comparison, he's not even in the same league.

As the young lady he attempts to scare puts it...

> *You look funny*

There's also a note in the [script](http://scriptdrive.net/attachment.php?aid=149) (*registration required*) about what she's saying in the background.

> **KIDS** (waking up walla): *What’s going on?/It’s the middle of the night./**He’s a little funny green guy....***

Comment: There's literally a guy who looks like the love child of a koosh ball and a barbell in the second movie. There's fluffballs that grow little legs. There's a guy whose* only possible method of scaring* was to simply stand somewhere and stare into space.

Comment: @Axelrod - Note his poor scores on the scare-meter.

Comment: There's definitely *something* going on. Maybe it's just a universe where a giant eye watching you in the darkness isn't scary, even relative to a doughy pink guy looking zoned out?

Comment: @Axelrod - His appearance is certainly startling, but that's not the same as scary.

Answer (score 11):

Armchair psychology time!

[Kids like childlike faces, and the signifiers include *big eyes* and *rounded faces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuteness#Preference_in_young_children):

> Borgi et al. stated that young children demonstrate a preference for faces with a more "infantile facial" arrangement i.e. a rounder face, a higher forehead, bigger eyes, a smaller nose and a smaller mouth. In a study that used three- to six-year-old children, Borgi et al. asserted that the children showed a viewing time preference toward the eyes of "high infantile" faces of dogs, cats and humans as opposed to "low infantile" faces of those three species.

Mike also has no nose, and no hair might work as a stand-in for a higher forehead.  Also as mentioned in the comments and other answer, although he has a large mouth, the teeth are blunted and not scary.

So the cuteness factor for audiences would simply be more pronounced in children.